# Post image and JSON data with one NSURLrequest

Tags: ios, django, json, curl, django-rest-framework

Im trying to upload an image from the client application to my django webserver. Im trying to create the equivalent of the following curl command using NSURLConnection.

```
curl -v  -S  -X POST  -H 'Accept: application/json' -F image=@"//Users/mackaiver/someImageOfACat.jpg;type=image/jpg"  -F kiosk="81" http://myurl.de/rest/image/
```

The expected response is the HTTP Status 201 Created and the server does expect some sort of JSON response I presume. When I use a curl line like this

```
curl -v  -S  -X POST  -H 'Accept: application/json' -F image=@"//Users/mackaiver/someImageOfACat.jpg;type=image/jpg" http://myurl.de/rest/image/
```

I expect a 400 Bad Request respone. So far so good. This works fine via curl on the command line. 
Now I want to do this in iOS. So far Im thinking I can use following code to send an image.

```
NSString *urlString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@image",REST_BASE_URL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);


NSString *boundary = @"----------------------------6f875f2289c9";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// file
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image_upload.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Now for some reason this creates a 200 OK response which is not at all what I expected. Also I dont know how to add the kiosk=81 parameter. Is there any way to do this? Should I use an external library like AFNetworking?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

This is what my code looks like now. Looking at the wireshark output from both the curl command and my app I cant seem to find any differences.

```
NSString *urlString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@image",BASE_URL];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];


NSString *boundary = @"--6ee875e2289c9";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
NSString *accept = @"application/json";

[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"bla.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"kiosk\"\r\n\r\n%@", kioskId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                   initWithRequest:request
                   delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Django web service expects a [multipart/form-data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data#Form_Data) request with:

- a `Accept: application/json` custom header field,
- `image` and `kiosk` parameters.

You know how to achieve this with curl, from the command line, thanks to the following options:

1. `-H/--header <line>` to set your custom header,
2. `-X POST` to issue a `POST` request,
3. `-F/--form <name=content>` to specify multipart POST data.

In Objective-C with `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest` you need to do the equivalent of the above options:

1. you can set a custom header on your `NSURLRequest` instance thanks to the `addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` method,
2. you can perform a `POST` request via `[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];`,
3. you need to set a properly formatted `body` string with `[request setHTTPBody:body];`.

So the question is: *how do I manually create a multipart/form-data body string with my image and kiosk parameters?*

The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388) and `curl --trace-ascii out.txt ...` may help you building the body (note that you need 2 boundary sections since you have 2 parameters).

Alternatively you can easily find many samples on how to do that, e.g: [Sending Multipart Forms with Objective-C](http://nthn.me/posts/2012/objc-multipart-forms.html).

At last, [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is a convenient wrapper around NSURLConnection. It is particularly handy since it provides a ready-to-use [`multipartFormRequestWithMethod`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/44915d517302a7c7a87fb6c8bf2bd22281e57964/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.h#L300) method used to perform multipart POST requests. So you can use it as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you! Im afraid I cant seem to get this to work. I compared the wireshark output from the curl command with the output from my app. I cant make out any differences. I updated my post to contain my most recent ios code. Maybe ill just try the AFNetworling bit.

Comment: I used the AFNetworking lib as described in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692102/send-image-along-with-other-parameters-with-afnetworking) SO question. Again the wireshark output looks similar to the curl post. Still I get a 200 OK response whatever data I send. I'd expect some 400 errors at least.

Comment: I got it to work with AFNetworking now :D Guess im gonna switch the whole application to use that library. Thanks again.

Comment: And what about the wireshark output w/ AFNetworking? You should refer to [AFStreamingMultipartFormData](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/44915d517302a7c7a87fb6c8bf2bd22281e57964/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m#L828) implementation and compare it with your code to understand what's wrong!