# Matching your specific HTML Form when using AFNetworking to upload image iOS

Tags: html, ios, afnetworking

I'm a total newbie to this HTML form post so I'm having some trouble deciphering how to implement this html form into a post using AFNetworking.  I need to add the ability to upload an image to the server from my app.  Could someone walk me through this.

Here is the HTML Form I am to use.

```
        <form action="http://myserver/uploadImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" size="45"/>
            <input type="text" name="caption" size="80"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload It"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="the user id"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="a token"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="an IPaddress"/>
        </form>
```

I have found a bunch of examples like the one below so I've got a good handle on the methods to use.  However the disconnect for me is how and where to put each of the fields contained in the html form above.
[send image along with other parameters with AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692102/send-image-along-with-other-parameters-with-afnetworking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually must simpler than I was making it.  I just didn't see any examples that put the parameters required in the form into the dictionary.  I will lay it out so anyone struggling to see the obvious like myself will have an example to use.

The code below is a direct copy from the link in my question with a few exceptions I'll point out.

```
NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadedImgView.image, 1.0);//(uploadedImgView.image);

if (imageToUpload)
{
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"My Image Caption", @"caption", userId, @"pid", @"openSesame", @"token", @"users ip address", "ip",  nil];

AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myServer"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/uploadImage" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSDictionary *jsons = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
     //NSLog(@"response: %@",jsons);

 }
                                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     if([operation.response statusCode] == 403)
     {
         //NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
         return;
     }
     //NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

 }];

[operation start];
```

}

The first thing to notice is the `NSDictionary *parameters`.  This is where you lay out your parameters required in the form.  So as you can see from the form in the question I needed a : caption, pid, token, and ip parameter along with all their respective values.

Looking at the form there is one more parameter I didn't mention.  Which is this line `<input type="file" name="file" size="45"/>` in particular.  That portion of the form is handled by this line of code.

```
[formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
```

The original question had `@"image"` for the `name:` value.  I fought this for about thirty minutes trying to figure out why I was getting a 500 response from the server when I noticed that my form was expecting `@"file"`.  Once I changed it everything worked properly.

Just as a note the `path:` parameter in `multipartFormRequestWithMethod:` is added on to the tail end of the baseURL.  So the request will go to `@"http://myserver/uploadImage"` as required in the action of the form.

Like I said I hope this spells out the obvious for those like me that tend to overlook it.