# Sending Image to server from IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

In my IOS app I want to send an image to the server along with Image name using HTTP request.
I am a programmer with embedded Background so not aware with HTTP calls, and quite new to iPhone  development also.

How can I accomplish this, any sample code or tutorials will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use AFNetworking framework to send pictures from mobile. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692102/send-image-along-with-other-parameters-with-afnetworking)

Answer (score 2):

The better approach is to first compress your image using [Image Compress Library Here](https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/UIImage-ImageCompress) and then upload it using and Networking library Liek AF Networking or you can also send it using NSUrlConnection. AFNetworking is easy to use. You can visit [this page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to see how to import this into your project then. Write these lines of codes.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://samwize.com/api/poo/"
   parameters:@{@"color": @"green"}
   constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you from my point of view would be to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

It'll send the image to a php page, then on the server, you build and save the image with the data sent.

[Here's](http://samwize.com/2014/05/10/tutorial-on-using-afnetworking-2-dot-0/) a basic tutorial, but lot of others on internet.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can do something like this by using [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request)

```
NSURL *strUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?action=youraction",serverUrl]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request;
request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:strUrl] autorelease];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];

NSString *imagePAth = userImagePath;

NSArray *imageName = [userImagePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

if( userImagePath)
{
    [request setFile:imagePAth withFileName:[imageName lastObject] andContentType:@"image/jpeg"                   forKey:@"profileImage"];
}

[request setUseCookiePersistence:NO];
[request setUseSessionPersistence:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];

[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

[request startAsynchronous];

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

{

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

}
```

Comment: which header files i need to include

Comment: #import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"

Comment: It will work but you have to add ASIHTTPRequest's all file from git link i have provided. Also need to add few frameworks too.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURLConnection, make sure that you convert images to NSData
user_id and key there are parameters.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:constFileUploadURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"0xLhTaLbOkNdArZ";

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *userid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",userID];
[body appendData:[userid dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[constBackendKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

for (NSData *data in arrayWithFiles)
{
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files%ld\"; filename=\"image%ld.jpg\"\r\n",[arrayWithFiles indexOfObject:data],[arrayWithFiles indexOfObject:data]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
_connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```